# Creating a User Time Sheet for a RoR Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profile

I'm kind of a newb to RoR and I'm working on creating my first web app.

So...My question is, how do I create a user time sheet in RoR?

What I need to do is create a classroom time sheet for students' (Users) reading times at home.

The students (Users) are able to sign up and have a profile created. From there, I would like for them to have access to log in their reading time(s).

I have attached examples of just some simple timesheets that would work perfectly for this.

I just do not know where to start and have not been able to find any gems that could help me create this.

**Time Sheet 1**
[image: timesheet 1]

**TimeSheet 2**
[image: timesheet 2]

Comment: So the pieces you need, as it sounds to me, are some basic pages, user authentication, and then time tracking (which would probably be in javascript, not ruby).  These are very broad topics however and can probably not be answered in a real direct way here.  I would look at a ruby on rails tutorial, something that has users sign in, a tutorial using a gem called devise might be easiest as it handles a lot for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. See [**Where to Start**](//meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6367/143094).

Answer (score 3):

#### Users: Ruby part

- Use [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem - it will save a lot of time for you.

Add Devise to user model (something like that: `rails generate devise User`), then autogenerate basic Devise pages (sign in, sign up, etc), see Devise tutorials:

- https://launchschool.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication
- http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise

Also you'll probably need something like `Job` model with fields `user_id`, `time_spent`, `date` or something.

#### Timesheets: JS part

Time tracking is more front-end part of work, so you'll need to write some JS scripts for time tracking, which will monitor user activity and then send it to Job mobel on Rails side.

Track time spent on page (example):

```
    var page_opened;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        page_opened = Date.getTime();

        $(window).unload(function () {
            page_closed = Date.getTime();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/save_user_time",
                data: {
                    'timeSpent': page_closed - page_opened,
                    'job_id': job_id
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

Also you defenetly should take a look on some basic Rails tutorials for better understanding:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
- https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-rails