# Ruby on Rails Model with calendar bar as columns and Primary Key from different model as rows?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and currently trying to program a company administration with it.
I managed to find a way to get employee's, orders and customers to work like they should. 
Now i am trying to find a way to create a timesheet for the employee's in which they can put in the hours they worked on each order a day for a month of time each, but i can't find a way to create a calendar model with rows were i could inherit my order list.

I know it maybe needed to see what i got so far. so here is the Git link, feel free to see what i did there. And i am always happy for valid criticism to help me clear faults i did and become better:
https://github.com/NerdOut/edu.verwaltung

This is how it should look:
[timesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwP7W.jpg)

On the left side the Orders in a Row, on top the calendar dates for the month.
I am not looking for the finished Code here, but for a tip how i can create a model like that, as i ran out of ideas. My other models are all simple Lists mostly with only basic connections between the models so an order knows to which customer it counts.

Comment: i already tried to work it out over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898412/creating-a-user-time-sheet-for-a-ror-web-app, https://github.com/squaremunkey/timesheet and https://github.com/gauravsaini23/timesheet, but it all wasn't doing what i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timesheet is not part of the model you are trying to reach, but just an interface for some data and its relations. I would create a model "WorkRecord" where you can save desired information, like: `WorkRecord(user_id, order_id, date, text, hours)`. So the new model would have to declare that it `belongs_to user` and `belongs_to order`, and also you should update user and order models with `has_many workrecords`. Not sure if the `text` part should be a fixed text, in which case it shoud also may be linked to another model (inexistent for now).

The migration has to be something like this:

`rails generate model WorkRecord datum:date text:string hours:integer user:belongs_to order:belongs_to`

The generator will create the associations also in User and Order models.

To paint this in your timesheet you only have to query this model by dates and loop through it painting in each row the data of the model and its relations.

Hope it helps!